# How to put two KSQLDB tables in the same index in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I have two tables in KSQLDB that I want to put in the same index in Elasticsearch

But the Elasticsearch Service Sink Connector for Confluent Platform does not support
topic changes like:

- io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Key
- io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Value

as seen in the documentation https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/current/overview.html#limitations

Are there other ways of doing it?

Comment: According to those docs, RegexRouter cannot be used, which contradicts their blog - https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/ . The simple answer is that the Connect tasks itself shouldn't dictate what transforms are used because they all happen before the connector Task logic is even executed ... I think the only limitation they are referring to is that the ES index mapping must be created ahead of time

Comment: Creating the index before running the connector works! Thanks a lot!